# Htaccess redirect if there's nothing after slash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, slash

If my website is www.site.com, and there's a shop at www.site.com/shop, how do I make it so that going to shop.site.com, if it doesn't have anything after / (for example shop.site.com/someItem wouldn't redirect) would redirect to www.site.com/shop?

Right now going to shop.site.com/someShopItem redirect correctly to www.site.com/someShopItem, and I need it to stay this way, only change the shop.site.com -> www.site.com/shop

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this rule in root .htaccess of `shop.site.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^shop\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.domain.com/shop/ [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Used this on a tester, doesn't redirect shop.domain.com to anything.

Comment: Don't use any tester, use it on your Apache server and make sure this is **very first** rule in your .htaccess

Comment: Still redirects only to www.domain.com. Should I paste the whole htaccess for you to check? Maybe some other rules are interfering

Comment: Turns out it was working from the start, but the damn thing was cached

Answer (score 0):

Since we have: `RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [OptionalFlags]` from the documentation.
I'm really not a pro for those rules but I guess something like that should be enough ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^shop.example.com/?$ http://www.example.com/shop
```

Which means: replace shop.site.com by www.site.com/shop.

Additionnaly you can test your htaccess with a checker (eg: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)